# Paginating tag list

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-pagination

I'm having trouble paginating my tag page which lists all the products that are associated to a tag (many to many). The tag page is found on slug. I have the lists of products associated with the tag ordered on the highest average rating from the reviews related to the products. Unfortunately, I cannot seem to get the paginate working. Does anyone know how I'd do this from the code below

Tables:

```
 products: id, name, price, approved
 tags: id, name, slug
 -products_tag: id, product_id, tag_id
 reviews: id, comment, rating, product_id
```

current code:

```
public function show($slug)
{
  //
  $tag = Tag::with(['products' => function ($query) {
         return $query->where('approved', '=', 1)
               ->leftJoin('reviews', 'reviews.products_id', '=', 'products.id')
               ->select('products.*', DB::raw('AVG(rating) as ratings_average' ))
               ->groupBy('id')
               ->orderBy('ratings_average', 'DESC');}])->where('slug', $slug)->first();
         return view('tags.show')->withTag($tag);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the end of your query you call the method fisrt(), you need to you the method paginate() to generate the variables that you need.